# built-in Java classes/methods to convert between binary, decimal, and octal?

Tags: java

i know of several general formulas for converting between binary, decimal, and octal, but i was wondering if java has any built-in methods or classes that convert between the three. for instance, in the Integer class, there are static methods such as toBinaryString, toOctalString, etc which allow for decimal conversion, but i haven't found any to convert the other way. anyone know of anything?

in particular, i am looking for methods to convert from octal and binary to decimal and between octal and binary

thanks! x

Answer (score 4):

Integer.parseInt takes an optional second parameter for the base to parse it in. So to get binary,

```
Integer.parseInt(value, 2);
```

Octal,

```
Integer.parseInt(value,8);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and Integer.toBinaryString(int i), Integer.toOctalString(int i) and Integer.toHexString(int i).  All of those are static method of the Integer class.

So to turn F hex into 1111 binary:

```
int fifteen = Integer.parseInt("F", 16);
String fifteenInBinary = Integer.toBinaryString(fifteen);
```

fifteenInBinary would equal "1111";

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Long.toBinaryString() or Long.toOctalString() to convert a decimal to binary or octal.

here are 2 methods that convert from binary to decimal and from octal to decimal, you could also convert from octal to decimal then to binary using these methods.

```
    public long binaryToDecimal(String binary) {
    long decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;
    for (int i = binary.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String digit = "" + binary.charAt(i);
        decimal += Integer.parseInt(digit) * Math.pow(2, power++);
    }
    return decimal;
}

public long octalToDecimal(String octal) {
    long decimal = 0;
    int power = 0;
    for (int i = octal.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String digit = "" + octal.charAt(i);
        decimal += Integer.parseInt(digit) * Math.pow(8, power++);
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about: [parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
parseInt("-FF", 16) returns -255
parseInt("1100110", 2) returns 102
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the method

```
Integer.toBinaryString(val);
```

The code may look like:

```
public class NewClass4 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int value;
    String binary;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    value=sc.nextInt();
    binary=Integer.toBinaryString(value);
    System.out.println(binary);
}

}
```